# Sql Server Compact with big dataset

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf

I am new to .NET and Desktop applications, I have an app with fairly big dataset about 600, 000 currently I am running with SQl Server Express, the problem is users might not have Sql Server Installed I started looking for alternatives came across SQl Server Compact But I am not sure If SQL Compact can handle 600, 000 records

any advise or help is appreciated

thanks you

Answer (score 2):

SQL CE can handle these many records. In one of my projects, I had one table with more than 2 million records.

Comment: Hi Manish thanks for the quick reply, what is the speed diff compare to sql server

Comment: SQL CE has its own limitations as it is a light weight version, but I don't think it will have any performance issue as such. I have implemented search(based on 4 parameters) for the 2 million plus records table I have mentioned and the search was pretty fast.

Comment: what orm did you use LINQ/Entity or Ado.NET